# How can i get all the values/rows of a table from Mysql database by clicking on a button in grails (.GroovyServerPages page)?

Tags: mysql, list, grails, gsp

how can i get all data from all the rows from a table into my Groovy Server Pages(GSP) page from `MySQL` database?
already have tried to get list but not successful.

```
def list(){
    def student1 = Student.getAll(1,2,3)
    [student:student1]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list(){
    [students: Student.list()]
}
```

and in your list.gsp

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${students}" var="student">
    <li>${student.id}</li> <!-- or other property -->
</g:each>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list()
{
 def Student= Student.getAll()
[students:Student]
}
```

and in your gsp you can loop through this object for all the records as "quindimildev" told above